# Elasticsearch: do not ignore type of the searched value

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I try this simple JSON to query Elasticsearch: `{"query" : {"bool" : {"must" : [{"terms" : {"a" : [1, 2, "3"]}}]}}, "from" : 0, "size" : 1000}`

What results I expect - all entries, where `a` is an integer `1` or `a` is an integer `2` or `a` is a **string** `"3"`.

I understand that one field in a DB can't have multiple types, question is about the query. ES version is 7.x (default settings) and in a document I index `a` is an integer.

But I still get results where `a` is an **integer** `3` - it had to be skipped, how to prevent such behavior? I wish Elasticsearch respects values type and returns the same types only.

Is that possible?

Comment: This depends on how you indexed your `a` field and what ES version you're using. The newer ones wouldn't even let you sync different types of array values. So can you elaborate?

Comment: @jzzfs, ES is 7.x (default settings) and the field `a` was indexed as an integer

Answer (score 0):

When you set the type of `a` as an integer, `3` will be cast to an integer.

`3a`, in contrast, would throw a `number_format_exception`.

---

Given that all your `a` values seem numeric, you can set a strict mapping that would prevent strings from indexing in the first place using `coerce`:

```
PUT myindex
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "a": {
        "type": "integer",
        "coerce": false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

which will throw the exception `Integer value passed as String` when you attempt this

```
POST myindex/_doc
{
  "a": "3"
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to prevent type casting or to make ES do not search other types other than integers in this case? I do not have plans to reindex all the data, so I'm thinking only about tweaking a search query

Comment: Since you've defined them as integers, they've already been cast to such. So I'm afraid there's no way to tweak the search query at this point.